# Merge [odor] into [smell]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [smell](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smell) is quite popular (86 questions, in the top 20 tags) and is to be used for

> Hacks related to dealing with smells and odours.

There's also an [odor](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odor) tag with only four questions. Can it be synonymized into [smell](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smell)? I could retag all questions, but somebody in the future could recreate the [odor](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odor) tag, and synonymizing/merging solves this problem once and forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes even more sense given that every question with [odor](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odor) also had the tag [smell](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smell).

Done.

Comment: Things don't smell, noses do. Things stink/have an odour. Merging these tags is ignorance.

Comment: Smell is both a noun and a verb.  Using *smell* avoids the inevitable edit wars over *odor* and *odour* that would ensue.